# I want to count cumulatively the number of previous repeating values

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

The input data frame looks like this:

| ID | Timestamp | Diff |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 10:00:00 | 6 |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 10:00:06 | 6 |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 10:00:18 | 12 |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 10:00:24 | 6 |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 10:00:30 | 6 |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 10:00:36 | 6 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 11:00:00 | 6 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 11:00:06 | 6 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 11:00:12 | 6 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 11:00:24 | 12 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 11:00:30 | 6 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 11:00:36 | 6 |

Applying this to the *diff* column would *result* in a new column of values

| ID | Timestamp | Diff | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 10:00:00 | 6 | 1 |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 10:00:06 | 6 | 2 |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 10:00:18 | 12 | 1 |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 10:00:24 | 6 | 1 |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 10:00:30 | 6 | 2 |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 10:00:36 | 6 | 3 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 11:00:00 | 6 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 11:00:06 | 6 | 2 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 11:00:12 | 6 | 3 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 11:00:24 | 12 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 11:00:30 | 6 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 11:00:36 | 6 | 2 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select     t.id
          ,t.timestamp
          ,t.diff
          ,row_number() over (partition by id, rn_global - rn_diff order by timestamp) as Result

from      (select  t.id
                  ,t.timestamp
                  ,t.diff
                  ,row_number() over (partition by id       order by timestamp) rn_global
                  ,row_number() over (partition by id, diff order by timestamp) rn_diff
           from    t
           ) t
           
order by  id, timestamp
```

--

```
+----+------------------------------+------+--------+
| id |          timestamp           | diff | Result |
+----+------------------------------+------+--------+
|  1 | 2021-01-01T10:00:00.000+0000 |    6 |      1 |
|  1 | 2021-01-01T10:00:06.000+0000 |    6 |      2 |
|  1 | 2021-01-01T10:00:18.000+0000 |   12 |      1 |
|  1 | 2021-01-01T10:00:24.000+0000 |    6 |      1 |
|  1 | 2021-01-01T10:00:30.000+0000 |    6 |      2 |
|  1 | 2021-01-01T10:00:36.000+0000 |    6 |      3 |
|  2 | 2021-01-01T11:00:00.000+0000 |    6 |      1 |
|  2 | 2021-01-01T11:00:06.000+0000 |    6 |      2 |
|  2 | 2021-01-01T11:00:12.000+0000 |    6 |      3 |
|  2 | 2021-01-01T11:00:24.000+0000 |   12 |      1 |
|  2 | 2021-01-01T11:00:30.000+0000 |    6 |      1 |
|  2 | 2021-01-01T11:00:36.000+0000 |    6 |      2 |
+----+------------------------------+------+--------+
```